# Python using tkinter and listbox can't get button to deliver answer

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Using python 3.6, tkinter and mathplotlib.

Created a listbox, but I can't figure out how to have each button return a different graph.

Created box

```
window.title( 'Employee Selection' )
frame = Frame( window )
listbox = Listbox( frame )
listbox.insert( 1 , '1')
listbox.insert( 2 , '2')
listbox.insert( 3, '3')
listbox.insert( 4, '4')
listbox.pack()
```

I use this

```
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', immediately)
print(listbox.get(ACTIVE))
```

How do I make it so when click `box 1` it chooses to run one thing
and `box 2` it chooses to run another...

here is the whole thing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tkinter import *

import tkinter.messagebox as box



# data to plot

n_groups = 4

scores_1 = (10,8,6,7)

scores_4 = (7,6,6,7)

scores_2 = (9,9,8,10)

scores_3 = (6,5,7,5)



def immediately(e):

    # create plot

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

         index = np.arange(n_groups)

        bar_width = 0.35

        opacity = 0.8


    rects1 = plt.bar(index, 1, bar_width,

                     alpha=opacity,

                     color='b',

                     label='Joe')

        plt.xlabel('Person')

        plt.ylabel('Rating')

        plt.title('Performance Ratings')

        plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))

        plt.legend()



        plt.tight_layout()

        plt.show()





window = Tk()

window.title( 'Employee Selection' )

frame = Frame( window )

listbox = Listbox( frame )

    listbox.insert( 1 , '1')

    listbox.insert( 2 , '2')

    listbox.insert( 3, '3')

    listbox.insert( 4, '4')

    listbox.pack()

btn = Button( frame , text = 'Select')

btn.pack( side = RIGHT , padx = 5)

listbox.pack( side = LEFT )

frame.pack( padx = 70 , pady = 30 )



listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', immediately)
print(listbox.get(ACTIVE))
mainloop()
```

button 1 is hard coded because i can't figure out how to choose the others

Comment: Please create [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're facing.

Comment: _"how to have each button return a different graph"_ - Your code has no buttons and no graphs.

Comment: where is function `immediately()` ? Your `listbox.get(ACTIVE)` is executed at start so it doesn't get selected element - you have to use it inside function `immediately()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get value inside function which you bind with `<<ListboxSelect>>`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_selection(event):
    # here you can get selected element
    print('previous:', listbox.get('active'))
    print(' current:', listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

    # or using `event`

    #print('event:', event)
    #print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))

    print('---')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(1, 'Hello 1')
listbox.insert(2, 'Hello 2')
listbox.insert(3, 'Hello 3')
listbox.insert(4, 'Hello 4')

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

root.mainloop()
```